# Hosting a Word 2016 / 365 Add-in using SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, office365api, office-js

**I am looking for ideas on how to make a Word Add-in work when hosted - and "manifest" managed by SharePoint / Office 365 Admin Centre.**

Curiously deployment via the old management studio works for Word 365 online - under "My Organisation" tab, which has vanished from the desktop client version.

I asked on the Microsoft community, but haven't reached a workable solution, even though William Zeng has been immensely helpful, but hasn't resolved the problem, I simply cannot host under a non secure site, and I don't want to go about building a content repository, when SharePoint is an excellent tool for the purpose.

That thread is here (*Edit URL corrected*):

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother/my-organisation-tab-missing-under-insert-my-addins/2018fbd3-18af-4103-874f-ffdff6929592

I have a successful SharePoint hosted add-in running via local file-share of the manifest, which is now used by a few hundred users (increasing daily).

But to really implement correctly I would like to host the manifest using the Office 365 management area (i.e. publish to all corporate machines which are running Office 365, and get away from the file-share model!

Office Admin Centre doesn't seem to understand - or be able to use SharePoint URLs, yet I chose SharePoint and 365 for the security of MFA and for useful, workflow managed hosting of approved content (which I serve via the add-in)

This worked for the online version of Word, but the online version of Word has performance problems, and search replace bugs, so is currently unworkable:

[image: Add-ins for Office Online]

Answer (score 1):

Jerry,

You say that My Organization has disappeared. Did you try readding it into the Trust Center within Word?

When you say "Office Admin Centre doesn't seem to understand - or be able to use SharePoint URLs" I'm not sure what section of Office Admin center you're referring to? Is it the centralized Deployment feature as discussed here or something else?
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-Admin-Center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f

Thanks
Phil

Comment: Thanks Phil, I went to get you the info and .. oops - seems my URL to the original ask has changed to an image url! That url should have been: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_winother/my-organisation-tab-missing-under-insert-my-addins/2018fbd3-18af-4103-874f-ffdff6929592

Comment: I don't have access to the "Admin Centre, so have to go by the names handed to me by our SharePoint architect, and from the help request.. This is what I am referring to: http://fud.community.services.support.microsoft.com/Fud/FileDownloadHandler.ashx?fid=4763d0ec-43a0-454b-8259-da244a754a3b

Comment: Still haven't resolved this. Essentially on a SharePoint 2013 tenant, if your manifest is formatted: IconUrl DefaultValue="https://companyportal.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/icon_32x32.png" and DefaultSettings
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://companyportal.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/add-in.html" it refuses to work. The deployment feature rejects the URLs as being incorrect. Do you know if Microsoft SharePoint store has the same issue? (is it worth me trying to deploy to Store)?